# RestSharp can't deserialize int body value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a service that returns an integer value like this example:

[image: WebAPI Integer Result]

Now, I´m trying to consume this service using Restsharp, like this:

```
    public static Task<T> ExecuteRequestAsync<T>(RestClient restClient, RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        restClient.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, response =>
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessful())
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response.Data);
            else
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(HandleResponseError(response));
        });

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private async Task<int> example() {

        //Get a new RestClient
        var restClient = new RestsharpManager.Builder()
            .WithAuthenticator(new RequestsAuthenticator())
            .Build();

        //Parameters
        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Method = Method.GET,
            Resource = "integration/install/size"
        };

        //Add parameters
        request.AddParameter("productID", productID);
        request.AddParameter("integrationID", integrationID);
        request.AddParameter("currentVersion", currentVersion);

        //Execute
        return await ExecuteRequestAsync<int>(restClient, request);         

    }
```

And as a result, we get the following error:
[image: Error after executing this request]

What are we missing? Another response types, like Poco classes, are deserialized correctly. Look that the 'content' attribute, shown in the 2nd image contains the correct value that should be displayed.

I know that I can manually parse it, but I'd like to know why  `restClient.ExecuteAsync<T>` isn't returning the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing the issue...

The 'Json Deserializer' that comes with the Restsharp isn't able to automatically deserialize this.

Implementing a 'Custom Deserializer' that is based on `Newtonsoft.Json` library solved the problem.

Bellow is the Custom Serializer/Deserializer and the way to use it:

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonSerializer : ISerializer, IDeserializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public static NewtonsoftJsonSerializer Default => new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new JsonSerializer
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        var content = response.Content;

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(content))
        {
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                return _serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
            }
        }
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string RootElement { get; set; }

    string ISerializer.ContentType
    {
        get { return "application/json"; }

        set { }
    }

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                _serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);

                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it to 'Serialize' your object, configure the `Request` as below:

```
    var request = new RestRequest
    {
        Method = Method.GET,
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        JsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default, //<= HERE!!!
        Resource = "integration/install/size"
    };
```

And also, register it to be the 'Default' JSON Deserializer:

```
    //Creates the RestClient...
    var restClient = new RestClient
    {
        BaseUrl = new Uri(_baseUrl),
        Authenticator = _authenticator
    };

    //Defines the jsonSerializer that will handle the responses
    var jsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default;
    restClient.AddHandler("application/json", jsonSerializer);
    restClient.AddHandler("text/json", jsonSerializer);
    restClient.AddHandler("text/x-json", jsonSerializer);
    restClient.AddHandler("text/javascript", jsonSerializer);
    restClient.AddHandler("*+json", jsonSerializer);
```